# Is Linq-XML always so messy?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

```
var subset = from item in document.Descendants("Id")
             where item.Value == itemId.ToString()
             select new PurchaseItem() {
                 Id = int.Parse(item.Parent.Element("Id").Value),
                 Name = item.Parent.Element("Name").Value,
                 Description = item.Parent.Element("Description").Value,
                 Price = int.Parse(item.Parent.Element("Price").Value)
             };
```

The structure of the XML is as follows:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        <Id></Id>
        <Name></Name>
        <Description></Description>
        <Price></Price>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

Id, and price are both integer values. Name and description are strings.

I've found `Linq to XML` great for what I've used it for, this is just a snippet. But, on the other hand I get the feeling it should or could be cleaner. The casting seems the most obvious issue in this snippet.

Any advice?

Comment: Try doing this using XmlReader, or even the old XML DOM, and you will reevaluate your view of 'messy'. ;)

Comment: The syntax here would be so much cleaner with dynamic. Imagine `ID = item.Id`, etc.

Comment: @Noldorin - 'untidy' would be more suitable then ;) My work with XMLReader in the past, now that was messy.

Comment: If you have the XSDs use you can use Linq to XSD (on codeplex) to generate a nicely typed library

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. Guess you have your answer at least, anyway. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually it would be better IMO to cast than to call `int.Parse`. Here's how I would write your query:

```
string id = itemId.ToString(); // We don't need to convert it each time!

var subset = from item in document.Descendants("Id")
             where item.Value == id
             let parent = item.Parent
             select new PurchaseItem
             {
                 Id = (int) parent.Element("Id"),
                 Name = (string) parent.Element("Name"),
                 Description = (string) parent.Element("Description"),
                 Price = (int) parent.Element("Price")
             };
```

Comment: John, any comment on why doint it this way, rather than the way I show it?

Comment: @Jon - How come .Value is not required? Is this called implicitly behind the scenes?

Comment: XElement defines custom casting operators for the common data types. So when you cast an XElement, you're really calling one of those operators, which reads the value and converts it. You refrain from explicitly calling `.Value` for two reasons: One, Value is a string, and those custom operators are defined on XElement, not string. Two, casting an XElement that happens to be null will just return null, while calling .Value on a null XElement will cause an exception. Useful when filtering.

Comment: @Mitchel: I tried to keep as close to the original as possible in terms of the search itself, just streamlining it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have an "Items" node as well?

You could do something like this, assuming that you are loading the document using XElement.Load()

```
var subset = from item in document.Elements("Item")
             where item.Element("Id").Value == itemId.ToString()
             select new PurchaseItem() {
                 Id = int.Parse(item.Element("Id").Value),
                 Name = item.Element("Name").Value,
                 Description = item.Element("Description").Value,
                 Price = int.Parse(item.Element("Price").Value)
             };
```

Not a lot better, but much easier to read!

Answer (score 1):

In your example you can tidy up a little bit by finding the `<Item/>` element rather than the `<Id/>` to avoid getting the `Parent` each time:

```
var subset = from item in document.Descendants("Item")
             where item.Element("Id").Value == itemId.ToString()
             select new PurchaseItem()
                        {
                            Id = int.Parse(item.Element("Id").Value),
                            Name = item.Element("Name").Value,
                            Description = item.Element("Description").Value,
                            Price = int.Parse(item.Element("Price").Value)
                        };
```

Comment: I orginially had this, but changed it after playing with the code. So +1 for showing me it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing a new constructor for `PurchaseItem` that takes the XML element, so you can write:

```
select new PurchaseItem(item.Parent);
```